# Issue with setting up time series correctly in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have been trying to do some basic analysis on some timeseries data. However, I keep getting this error on anything I am trying to do

```
Error in decompose(data_ts, type = c("additive")) : 
 time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

I assume the problem is that I am not setting the data correctly for time series analysis. I am working with data that runs M-F for about a year. Below is the code that I am using to convert the series to time series

```
train=xts(data$x,as.Date(data$Date,format='%m/%d/%Y'),frequency=365)
data_ts=as.ts(train)
attributes(data_ts)
$tsp
[1]   1 277   1
$class
[1] "ts"
```

But when I try to do any type of analysis on the time series data, I receive this:

```
dcomp=decompose(data_ts,type=c('additive'))
Error in decompose(data_ts, type = c("additive")) : 
time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

Am I setting up the time series incorrectly? Is there a better period that I should pick for frequency because technically I don't have a full year worth of data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the `xts` frequency argument doing the same thing as the `ts` frequency argument.

So, I assume you need to convert your data into a `ts` object before you use `decompose`. The way I got it to work is the following:

Using the following data:

```
data(sample_matrix)
df <- as.data.frame(sample_matrix )
df$date <- as.Date(row.names(df))
```

If I do the following:

```
dfxts <- xts(df[1:4], order.by=df$date, frequency=12)
decompose(dfts)
Error in decompose(dfts) : time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

I get the same error as you.

However if I convert it into a `ts` object and use that frequency argument:

```
#use as.ts to convert into ts
#make sure your data frame consists of numeric columns otherwise it will fail
#drop all the others
#in my case df[1:4] has numeric values. I use the date as a separate vector.
dfts <- as.ts(xts(df[1:4], order.by=df$date))
#I guess splitting by month would make sense in your case.
#I think ts works with frequency 4 (quarterly) or 12 (monthly)
#If you see your dfts now you ll see the difference
dfts <- ts(dfts, frequency=12)
```

And then it works:

```
dcomp <- decompose(dfts)
```

Output:

```
> str(dcomp)
List of 6
 $ x       : mts [1:180, 1:4] 50 50.2 50.4 50.4 50.2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Open" "High" "Low" "Close"
  ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 1 15.9 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "mts" "ts" "matrix"
 $ seasonal: Time-Series [1:720] from 1 to 60.9: -0.00961 0.02539 0.06149 0.01773 -0.00958 ...
 $ trend   : mts [1:180, 1:4] NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 1 15.9 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "mts" "ts"
 $ random  : mts [1:180, 1:4] NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 1 15.9 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "mts" "ts" "matrix"
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "x - seasonal.x.Open" "x - seasonal.x.High" "x - seasonal.x.Low" "x - seasonal.x.Close"
 $ figure  : num [1:12] -0.00961 0.02539 0.06149 0.01773 -0.00958 ...
 $ type    : chr "additive"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "decomposed.ts"
```

Comment: that worked for getting the data into the right time series format. However, when I used frequency=12, the data goes into 2035. Any suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: This is really strange. It has never happened to me before. I know that the frequency argument isn't the easiest to work with, but I have never had that. You probably need to include the data as well otherwise it will be difficult to tell. I guess it is a data related problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about changing the frequency. Right now, you're saying there would be 365 observations per period, so you have less than 1 period of data. You could adjust it to set the frequency to 5, since you're getting 5 observations per week. That's not the only option, just an example that should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this general approach with your data-set:

```
# Pre-loading the data
library(TSA)
library(mgcv)
#Choose the 'Temp Monthly.csv' dataset, wherever it is located on your computer
#Additionally, just skip this step and replace ‘fname’ with the files direct location
fname <- file.choose()
#Load Data
data <- read.csv(fname)
data <- data[,2]
#Convert to TS data in proper frame
temp <- ts(data,start=c(1950,1),freq=12)
# Plotting Time Plots
ts.plot(temp,ylab="Temperature")
abline(a=mean(temp),b=0,col='red')
```

This might help. And for more details about time series in R, this article in medium might be helpful: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/time-series-analysis-101-in-r-and-python-1e1a7f7c3e51

Please feel free to comment if you need any help on this. :)